# Prestashop 1.6 core controller override

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I am currently trying to override a core controller protected function within PrestaShop 1.6.1. The controller is AddressController.php
The override controller looks like:

```
class AddressController extends AddressControllerCore
{


    /**
     * Assign template vars related to countries display
     */
    protected function assignCountries()
    {
        $this->id_country = (int)Tools::getCountry($this->_address);
        // Generate countries list
        if (Configuration::get('PS_RESTRICT_DELIVERED_COUNTRIES')) {
            $countries = Carrier::getDeliveredCountries($this->context->language->id, true, true);
        } else {
            $countries = Country::getCountries($this->context->language->id, true);
        }

        // @todo use helper
        $list = '';
        $product_by_country = Configuration::get('TOOLPRODUCTCOUNTRY_PRICE');
        foreach ($countries as $country) {
            if($product_by_country==1){
                if (isset(Context::getContext()->cookie->productcountry_delivery)) { 
                    $selected = ((int)$country['id_country'] === Context::getContext()->cookie->productcountry_delivery) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                } else {
                    $selected = ((int)$country['id_country'] === $this->id_country) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
                }
            } else {
                $selected = ((int)$country['id_country'] === $this->id_country) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            }
            $list .= '<option value="'.(int)$country['id_country'].'"'.$selected.'>'.htmlentities($country['name'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8').'</option>';
        }

        // Assign vars
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'countries_list' => $list,
            'countries' => $countries,
            'sl_country' => (int)$this->id_country,
        ));
    }

}
```

Basically I want to show in the checkout steps as default country another one than selected in PrestaShop BO for the `$('#id_country')` drop down list. The country desired is chosen before the checkout process and is stored as `productcountry_delivery`.
The problem is that this code is not taken into consideration by Prestashop, as if it wouldn't exist.
I removed the class_index.php from cache folder to force a recompile but yet again with no succes

Could someone help me figure this out?

Thank you!

Comment: Make sure to save the override file in this location
`override/controllers/front/AddressController.php`

Comment: The location of the file is correct.  The problem resides somewhere else

Comment: Open the file class_index.php and check if the class is really overridden, you should find a line that says `'path' => 'override/controllers/front/AddressController.php',`, if not then it's a PS bug of some sort or a read permission problem maybe

Comment: Already done that.  The file exists and is overridden...